# NodeJS export is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two files and try to link them together:

**x.js**

```
var y = require('./y.js');

var ts = function ()
{

         y.myfunct();

}
module.exports = {
        ts: ts,
};
```

**y.js:**

```
var x = require('./x.js');

var cb = function()
{
        console.log ('works');
}

x.ts();

module.exports = {
        cb: cb,
};
```

Why do i get:

x.js:8
     y.cb();
       ^

TypeError: y.cb is not a function

error?

Comment: it's a circular dependency - that's the reason it's not working

Comment: You have circular references. Not good.

Comment: you have circular reference also where is myfunct?

Comment: is there a way to avoid this?  file1 calls function in file2, after processing a function in file1 is called, is this not possible?

Comment: You have a circular dependency which does not work in node.js. 
Restructure your code to not have have `x` loading `y` and `y` loading `x`.  This is a code architecture issue and you need to break things into modules differently so that if `x` is going to load `y`, then `y` does not attempt to load `x`.  There are lots of ways to reorganize.  For example, you can put common code in a third module or combine both of these into the same module.